# Symbol of compactly embedding

Tags: symbols

[image]

What latex command does this symbol allow?

Comment: $\hookrightarrow$

Comment: Do you mean a pair of arrows?

Answer (score 6):

With `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\dhookrightarrow{\mathrel{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackanchor[.1ex]{\hookrightarrow}{\hookrightarrow}}
}}
\begin{document}
$a \dhookrightarrow b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it across math styles:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\dhookrightarrow{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\abovebaseline[-.6\LMex]{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackanchor[.15\LMex]{\SavedStyle\hookrightarrow}{%
  \SavedStyle\hookrightarrow}}}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \dhookrightarrow b$\par
$\scriptstyle a \dhookrightarrow b$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle a \dhookrightarrow b$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that the command that you are after is `\hookrightarrow`. You can find [here](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) the answers to questions such as that one.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want two arrows one above the other.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compemb}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\comp@emb\relax}}
\newcommand{\comp@emb}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{$#1##$\cr\hookrightarrow\cr\noalign{\vskip1pt}\hookrightarrow\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A\compemb X
\]

\end{document}
```

This also scales in subscripts and superscripts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it looks better if the heads of the arrows are a little smaller, like those of the [`old-arrows`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/old-arrows) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}
\newlength{\hookwidth}
\newlength{\hookheight}
\settowidth{\hookwidth}{$\varhookrightarrow$}
\settoheight{\hookheight}{$\varhookrightarrow$}
\newcommand{\compemb}{%
    \mathrel{%
        \raisebox{-.35\hookheight}{$\varhookrightarrow$}\hspace*{-\hookwidth}%
        \raisebox{ .55\hookheight}{$\varhookrightarrow$}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\(A \compemb X\)
\end{document}
```

Loading `old-arrows` with the `old` option will not affect the commands defined by `amsmath`, since the commands introduced by `old-arrows` are all defined with a `\var` prefix with this option.